# Saving For /f parameter in every loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a Batch script that should use a `.cfg` to get certain information.
With "#" I can comment out in my `cfg`, that works fine. But now I also want to safe `%%b` from every loop in a different variable. How do I do that?

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL enableextensions

FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (.\test_2.44.cfg) DO (
    set x=%%a 
    IF "!x:~0,1!"=="#" (
        echo skipped
        ) else (
            echo %%b

        )
)
```

The .cfg

```
# 
# test
#
NAME_LOGDATEI=.\test2.44.log
NAME_CSV=.\test_2.44.csv
#START_DIR=c:\windows
START_DIR=%ProgramFiles%
```

I want `.\test2.44.log`, `.\test_2.44.csv` and `%ProgramFiles%` each in a different variable. Now it just gives me the result of the last loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set /a counter=1
FOR /f "eol=# tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (.\test_2.44.cfg) DO (
   set "res[!counter!]=%%b"
   set /a counter=counter+1
   rem --OR--
   set %%a=%%b
)

echo %START_DIR%  -- %NAME_LOGDATEI%
echo %res[1]% -- %res[2]%
```

to skip the lines starting with `#` you can use `eol=#` in for /f options.
to save all the lines you can use pseudo array or to use the `%%a` token as variable name.